# How to get winID on wayland?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, wayland, qtwayland

This is my test code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
window.show()
print("Your winID: {}".format(window.winId()))
app.exec()
```

If I run it on X11, it can return the right number. But if I run it on Wayland, it just returns 1.

```
❯ python ./winID_test.py
Your winID: 1
```

I have searched [some informations](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76983) about this problem,but I didn't find any solution.

I want to display pythonOCC on pyside,and `qtViewer3d` depend on winId(`self._display.Create(window_handle=int(self.winId()), parent=self)`).

Comment: That bug lists another one which shows the current status of the problem: unresolved. So, it cannot be done, at least, right now under Qt.